# Função para gerar caracteres alfanuméricos aleatórios

Tags: c#, .net, string, random

Preciso de uma função em C# que gere uma `String` de caracteres alfabéticos e numéricos aleatórios de tamanho `N`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Segue a função que recebe como parâmetro a quantidade de caracteres de retorno, e retorna uma `string`.

```
public static string alfanumericoAleatorio(int tamanho)
{
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, tamanho)
                  .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                  .ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

É utilizado `Enumerable.Repeat` que serve para gerenciar uma sequência que contém um valor repetido, que recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro é o valor a ser repetido e o segundo é o numero de vezes que se repete.

Depois é utilizado o método `Select` do `LINQ`, iterando a cada linha e utilizando a expressão `random.Next`que recebe como parâmetro um `int32` que representa o numero máximo de retorno.

Dentro do `select` tem a expressão `s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]` , no caso `s` é uma linha com esse conteúdo = `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"`
`random.Next(s.Length)` vai gerar um numero aleatório pegando um carácter da `string`, onde `s.Length` é tamanho total de caracteres da `string`.

`.ToArray()` coloca todos os caracteres retornados em uma array de caracteres.

`new string()` transforma essa array de caracteres em uma string.